Regex replace with a small text change?
I need to convert some HTML content to UBB code, for instance replacing the < > signs by square brackets [ ].
There also may be an ordered list <ol> tag with a start= attribute specifying the kind of marker.


const str = '<b>Something</b> is going on.<br><i>But what?</i><br><br><ol start="3"><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ol>';
const regex = /<(\/?([bisu]|li|ul|ol|ol start="\d+"))>/gi;
let result = str.replace(regex, "[$1]");
console.log(result);



This works as expected, but I'd like to remove the quotation marks, so the <ol start="3"> will become [ol start=3]. I wonder if this is possible in the same regex.

I'd strongly suggest using an existing UBB parser library for this instead of rolling your own, eg. https://github.com/zmmbreeze/UBBParser

In fact, there are only 7 tags available.
Using a full parser library seemed a bit overkill:
<i></i>
<s></s>
<u></u>
<a href=...></a>
<ul></ul>
<ol start=""><//ol>```

@RoryMcCrossan They're going HTML->UBB, so they need an HTML parser.

JavaScript has a built-in DOM parser.

@Barmar the library I linked to coverts to/from both formats

As I wrote above, in this older UBB variant the tag must be [ol start=3]and [li], not [list=3] and [*]. You are right in case of extra spaces, but that won't happen since the HTML is generated dynamically.

What should happen to <br> ?

Sorry, they are converted to \n and should not be in the example.

This can be accomplished with minimal changes by adding a replacement function. The function adds the square brackets and removes quote marks. It uses a template literal for formatting, though that's optional.
Per comments, this answer assumes the input string is narrowly confined and that the output is a UBB variant where lists are defined as [ol] rather than [list].


const str = '<b>Something</b> is going on.<br><i>But what?</i><br><br><ol start="3"><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ol>';

const regex = /<(\/?([bisu]|li|ul|ol|ol start="\d+"))>/gi;

let result = str.replace(regex, (a,b) => `[${b.replace(/"/g,'')}]`)

console.log(result);




Hey, that's interesting! Now I need to understand that (a,b) mystery...

Found it on the linked page: "Specifying a function as the replacement".
